# Checking what seed is used by Random class

Tags: c#, .net, random, random-seed

Is is possible to check what seed is used by `Random` class?

I am using Random() class and then Next(int, int) method do generate some integer numbers for later calculations. I need the program to run on different random numbers each time, but I am experiencing sometimes errors I would like to investigate.
Is it possible to get the seed from Random class, so in case off errors I could use the same seed again and get the same random generated numbers?

Answer (score 3):

I think instead of checking that out, **you should create a Random object with the seed you want**.

```
Random rnd1 = new Random(); // Different seed every run
Random rnd2 = new Random(1234); // Always generates the same numbers sequence
```

The Random() constructor **uses the system clock to provide a seed value**. This is the most common way of instantiating the random number generator.

Check **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx)** for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the seed the `Random` was constructed with, as the value is not stored past the constructor.

See the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,bb77e610694e64ca) of `System.Random` for details.

You could create a wrapper for `System.Random` which does store the seed you created it with, and use that class instead.

```
class MyRandom : Random
{
    public readonly int Seed;

    public MyRandom(int seed) : base(seed)
    {
        Seed = seed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use reflection on Random instance?

Otherwise you can use a wrapper for storing the seed value or even have the wrapper to create a file with the seed value. And when testing the whole process load the seed from the file again to produce same pseudo-random values.